# Cross Browser input field width not setting properlly

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

The input field width is not commenly set in browsers like chrome and firefox.see my code below

```
 <table border="1" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="25%" style="margin-top: -90px;">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><input id="ir-box" type="checkbox"/>Only show LIVE reports</td><td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><input type="text" value="Keyword Search"/></td><td>{% include "buttons/go.html" %}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><input id="incident-types"class="incident-type" type="text" value="All Incident types" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><input id="location-types"class="incident-type" type="text" value="All Location types"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">From</td><td colspan="2">To</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" width="30"><input class="datefield" id="fromdate" type="text" value="dd/mm/yyyy"/></td><td colspan="2"  width="150"><input class="datefield" id="todate" type="text" value="dd/mm/yyyy"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td><td>{% include "buttons/go.html" %}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

css.

```
.datefield {
  padding:0; 
  margin:0; 
  width:80px;
  height:20px;
  }

  .incident-type {
  padding:0; 
  margin:0; 
  width:250px;
  height:20px; 
  }
```

May i know how to resolve this compatibility.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is not in the input field, but on table scale, try out my code on demo

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper"> 
<table border="1" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="25%">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><input id="ir-box" type="checkbox"/>Only show LIVE reports</td><td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><input type="text" value="Keyword Search"/></td><td>{% include "buttons/go.html" %}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><input id="incident-types"class="incident-type" type="text" value="All Incident types" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><input id="location-types"class="incident-type" type="text" value="All Location types"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">From</td><td colspan="2">To</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" width="30"><input class="datefield" id="fromdate" type="text" value="dd/mm/yyyy"/></td><td colspan="2"  width="150"><input class="datefield" id="todate" type="text" value="dd/mm/yyyy"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td><td>{% include "buttons/go.html" %}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    width: 400px;
}
.wrapper table {
    width: 100%;
}
.datefield {
  padding:0; 
  margin:0; 
  width:80px;
  height:20px;
  }

  .incident-type {
  padding:0; 
  margin:0; 
  width:250px;
  height:20px; 
  }
```

**DEMO**

```
http://jsfiddle.net/sqJyw/3/
```

**EXPLANATION**

I added div which wrap your table and table is retched to 100%